# How to retrieve Image from Resources folder of the project in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

i Have some images in resources folder in my project but i want to change the picture box from these resource files of the project

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192054/158288

Comment: This is better solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp/1192072 - for people coming later.

Answer (score 28):

Consider using [`Properties.Resources.yourImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(VS.80).aspx)

[`Properties.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(VS.80).aspx) contains everything that you've added as a resource (see your project properties, resources tab)

Other than that, if you embed the images as resource in your project, you can get at them by calling [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) on the assembly that you've embedded the images in, something like

```
Stream imgStream = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
    "YourNamespace.resources.ImageName.bmp");
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(imgStream);
```

Don't forget to mark the image as an embedded resource!  (You'll need to set the build action for the image in its properties window)

If you're finding that you keep getting back `null` from [`GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx), you may be giving the wrong name.  (It can be hard to get the names right)  Call [`GetManifestResourceNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx) on the assembly; that will give you back all the resource names, and you can find the one in the list that you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
string img = null;

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imgName;
    img = textBox1.Text;
    imgName = "images/" + img + ".jpg";

    if (imgName == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no photo");
    }
    else if (imgName != null)
    {
        this.picBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images/" + img + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the Code to Fetch Image From Resources Folder. Normally we keep images in Resources Folder. but Sometime we have image name only with us. in that case you can Access images from Resources Folder using Image Name only.

Below Code will Demonstrate about it.

```
private System.Resources.ResourceManager RM = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("YourAppliacationNameSpace.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);

PbResultImage.Image = (Image)RM.GetObject(YourPictureName);
```

- **YourAppliacationNameSpace** means name of your Application.
- **YourPictureName** means the Picture you Want to access from Resources Folder. but Picture name must be without Extension e.g. (PNG, GIF, JPEG etc)

hope i will be beneficial to some one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project. Go to Resources tab. Select the existing option and add the image.

[image]

Now access in the code by

```
Image = Properties.Resources.ImageName
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
(Bitmap) Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ImageName");
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for your control too, if you need to call your control by a string or concatenated reference.

Just call the control type first (in this case, a picturebox). Assume i=some number and d=some string:

```
var i = <some number>;
var d = <some string>;

((PictureBox)this.Controls["pictureBox" + i.ToString()]).Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("dice" + d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it's Possible

`pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.yourImagename;`

Comment: This is the same as the top answer.