# How to insert image from Image Resource File (not from the file system) in email?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, embedded-resource

I'm trying to insert a signature image into emails sent from my application. I know how to insert an image using `LinkedResource` and `AlternateView`, but those use a file from the file system. I'm trying to use a Resource File (e.g. `Properties.Resources.myLogo`). How does one achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the image from a resource stream. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-in-c-sharp) stackoverflow post should explain how to do it.