# How to attach a resource (an image for example) with the exe file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't know if I asked it right, but basically what happened is that I made a winform app which loads its image from the resource folder.

The problem is that when I build the project and get the exe and give it to a friend, he won't have that resource folder like I do, so he'll get an error saying missing file.

How can I somehow mix, or combine, or attach the image with my app?

Comment: Do you need to update the image, or allow users to add images?  Or are these static images that will not change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from resources in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @MystereMan I don't think it's a dup (or at least not of the one you mention).  This question is about how to embed the image; the other one is how to load the image.

Comment: @MystereMan ThanX man, as you said, I'm not trying to load the image.
About your Question, Yes, The user has the Ability to change the background image of the form.
(There is a Theme ComboBox where the user selects a theme)

Comment: @Beska - True, so I guess I just answered his next obvious question ;)

Comment: My point is, can the user muck about with the images?  Can they include their own?  If so, you can't really use an embedded resource (although you could write some logic that uses embedded resources if the user is not using their own).  You might be better off writing an installer that will install your application (including adding it to the start menu) and copy any additional files that are needed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant as Beska said .. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[image: App Properties Window]

You need to add it to the project by navigating to the Properties Window and going to the resource tab and adding the image from there.

Alternatively, from the PictureBox Control you can import resource from your computer.

[image: Option 2]

Comment: You can also include the image in your project, and mark it's build type to be Embedded Resource.

Comment: agreed, but when I've done that it wasn't visible in the Resources Mgr Area.

Comment: @MystereMan so after I mark it, if i wanna load it, should I load it from the resource file ?
I mean, should I do this: string path = "imagePath\\image.jpg";
and then load it like: BackGround = Image.FromFile(path);

Comment: so if do this, I don't have to send my friend the resource file with the exe right ?

Comment: no its embedded.  you should send your friend what is in the 'bin' folder

Answer (score 5):

if you don't need to update it in the future, compile your program with the image property build action set to embedded resource. 
if you need to change it in the future compile with property build action set to content.

Comment: May I ask you where Can I reach that ?

Comment: just right click on the image file from the file explorer in visual studio and select properties, one of the properties is 'build action'. Change it to embedded resource or content. its default value is None.

Comment: Thank you so much :)
but Can you tell me the difference between "Embedded Resource" and "Content" ?

Comment: @VeXe - Content does not embed the resource, Embedded Resource does.

Comment: If you want to change image once you made the build you can't do it if you marked the image as Embedded resource. Instead if you marked it as Content you can change whenever you want