# Trying to add image to resources programatically. System.ArgumentException occurs when setting image source

Tags: c#, image, winforms, jpeg, picturebox

I have been trying to add an image to resources programatically, following instructions from [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367(v=vs.71).aspx).

Here is a picture of my code and the error:

[image: ArgumentException was unhandled]

Maybe the error is due to image location. I have put it in

```
Projects\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\bin\Debug
```

What I need: import the image to resources for later use.

edit:
VS suggeted to use Image.bitmap and I have. But it is still not working.
I have tried these 4 ways
[image]

Comment: You don't add anything to resources programmatically.  Resources are compiled into your EXE when you build and then you use them at run time.  Your EXE can't recompile itself at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it fails to get your image from resources. Add image to your Resources and access through resources.

```
Bitmap image= new Bitmap(Application1.Properties.Resources.Gooner);
```

[How to add image to resources.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550441/in-c-sharp-winform-how-to-attach-a-resource-an-image-for-example-with-the-exe)

**Edit** (If you want to load the file)

```
        // Construct an image object from a file in the local directory.
        // ... This file must exist in the solution.
        Image image = Image.FromFile("Gooner.jpg");

        pb.Image = image;
```

Comment: You are right. But I nees to add it to resources, programatically

Comment: @AhmedFaizan: The issue in your code is that it cannot find the image. Why did you comment out InitializeComponents method? It should be the first line in the Form constructor normally.

Comment: @AhmedFaizan: What is your requirement? Did you want to user to select any image and set in the PictureBox or do you want to add an image included in your solution?

Comment: I have un-commented the initialize part and I want to add an image to the solution. I can add it to picture box later if I want.

Comment: @AhmedFaizan: I guess you haven't included your image to the solution. If you have included it in the solution Image.FromFile should work.

Comment: With all due respect, I have put it in every nook and cranny of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`Bitmap.FromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx) static method:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.FromFile("path_to_file.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback,
When I give the path to the file VS displays error in the "\" area.
Do I need to use "\\"
when writing the image source
something like:

Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\\bin\\Debug\\Gooner.jpg"

Comment: Yes. Or just add @ before your string like: @"Visual Studio 2015\Projects..."

Answer (score 0):

You should put your file not to this path:

```
Projects\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\bin\Debug
```

but to this:

```
Projects\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically\AddToVSResourcesProgramatically
```

Also it's not necessary to copy file manually. To do it automatically - you should find your image in your project's file list and choose Properties. Now, change the property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.

Comment: I have put it there as well but the same error comes

Comment: Can you please provide printscreen with your project's file list?