# Load image from resources

Tags: c#, image, resources, picturebox

I want to load the image like this:

```
void info(string channel)
{
    //Something like that
    channelPic.Image = Properties.Resources.+channel
}
```

Because I don't want to do

```
void info(string channel)
{
    switch(channel)
    {
        case "chan1":
            channelPic.Image = Properties.Resources.chan1;
            break;
        case "chan2":
            channelPic.Image = Properties.Resources.chan2;
            break;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What type of application are you working in? WinForms, WPF?

Comment: @xr280xr I'd guess WinForms from the PictureBox tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can always use `System.Resources.ResourceManager` which returns the cached `ResourceManager` used by this class. Since `chan1` and `chan2` represent two different images, you may use `System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(string name)` which returns an object matching your input with the project resources

**Example**

```
object O = Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("chan1"); //Return an object from the image chan1.png in the project
channelPic.Image = (Image)O; //Set the Image property of channelPic to the returned object as Image
```

**Notice**: `Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(string name)` may return `null` if the string specified was not found in the project resources.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Note: You need the "using x.y.z.Properties;" to make this work. Or else "Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(channel)" like in Wouter Huysentruit's answer. Using System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject directly will not work.

Comment: I like the notice mentioned in the end!

Answer (score 11):

You can do this using the [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx):

```
public bool info(string channel)
{
   object o = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(channel);
   if (o is Image)
   {
       channelPic.Image = o as Image;
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this for WPF

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WpfGifImage001;Component/Images/Progess_Green.gif"));
picBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sri.Stream);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Note to users, just do `"pack://application:,,,/Images/your_file.gif"` if you just want a file that's in your `Images` folder in VS.  You can also return it to a `Bitmap` if you just cast the `FromStream` line to that, if you so desire.

Answer (score 4):

ResourceManager will work if your image is in a resource file. If it is just a file in your project (let's say the root) you can get it using something like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = assembly .GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName." + channel);
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

Or if you're in WPF:

```
    private ImageSource GetImage(string channel)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/TestApp;component/" + channel, UriKind.Relative));
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.BeginInit();
        bmp.StreamSource = sri.Stream;
        bmp.EndInit();

        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
    this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
    this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(444, 25);
    this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
    object O = global::WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("best_robust_ghost");

    ToolStripButton btn = new ToolStripButton("m1");
    btn.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
    btn.Image = (Image)O;
    this.toolStrip1.Items.Add(btn);

    this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add an image resource in the project then (right click on the project and choose the *Properties* item) access that in this way:

```
this.picturebox.image = projectname.properties.resources.imagename;
```