# How to Access all images form Resource folder In winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to populate my imagelist control by images. For this i want to extract images from resource folder.

I have tried and searched over Google. But i found i can access only one image at a time from resource folder

I have tried in the following way:

```
Properties.Resources.ImageName  //Accessing a single image by a name
```

I want to populate my imagelist by images from resource folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources)

Comment: Check out the [ResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Why don't you just add your images to the ImageList using the designer? What's the point of loading items dynamically from a static resource?

Comment: I want to provide user to add images in a folder as their need then they can see these images to listview control .I think adding images to imagelist at design time is not user friendly .

Comment: Might not be worth the hassle, if I'm allowed to say that. Would it not be user friendly to allow a drag & drop of files or to provide a file open dialog?