# Images not displayed after executing exe setup for other windows machines

Tags: c#

I have created c# windows application for calender.
When i have created the setup file and after execution of it on other machine, i did not able to get the all images on application.

code is as under.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections;


namespace calender
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    int filelength = 0;

    System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker month;

    public Form2()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        //pass current month in string
        string dm = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();


        //declare condition of display month wise image
        if (dm =="1")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation ="";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
         }
        else if (dm == "2")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "BFeb.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "3")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "CMar.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "4")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "DApril.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "5")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "EMay.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "6")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "FJune.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "7")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "GJully.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "8")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "HAug.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "9")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "ISep.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "10")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "JOct.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "11")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "KNov.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
        }
        else if (dm == "12")
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"E:\Khadse\calender\calender\Image\LDec.png";
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(300, 300);
          }
    }

    private int _pictureIndex = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        System.IO.DirectoryInfo inputDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Khadse\calender\calender\Image"); //Source image folder path
        try
        {
            if ((inputDir.Exists))
            {

                //Get Each files 
                System.IO.FileInfo file = null;
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo eachfile in inputDir.GetFiles())
                {
                    file = eachfile;
                    if (file.Extension == ".png")
                    {
                        alist.Add(file.FullName); //Add it in array list
                        filelength = filelength + 1;
                    }
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[0].ToString());  //Display intially first image in picture box as sero index file path
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    //if user click Previous then show lower previous arraylist value image 
    private void btnprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i - 1 >= 0)
        {

            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i - 1].ToString());
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
    //if user click "Next" then show next arraylist value image 
    private void btnnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i + 1 < filelength)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(alist[i + 1].ToString());
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }



    //dragable window code
    int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    bool mouseDown;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            mouseX = MousePosition.X - 200;
            mouseY = MousePosition.Y - 20;

            this.SetDesktopLocation(mouseX, mouseY);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I saw an absolute path "E:\Khadse\calender..." at some places in your code. Are you sure, that this path also exists on the target machine?

Comment: that was my actual problem, how to change the path so that it will get to all machines so on

Comment: If your application uses images, which are fix at compile time, a better way is to embed them as resources into your application. See[Load image from resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources) for details.

Comment: If you need the images as external files, you could store them inside your application folder (e.g. MyApplication\images) or set the path in app.config.