# c# Get name of resource in variable string then use it As bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, resources

How can i just want to use my variable string like name of resource file.

For example Using Resources look like :

```
 bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.waypoint1, bmpScreenshot, out location);
```

As you see there i use resource named : waypoint1. I need to do something like that :

```
 string wpt1 = "waypoint1";
```

But i can't just do it simple like that :

```
bool success = FindBitmap(Properties.Resources.wpt1, bmpScreenshot, out location);
```

Could someone give an simple example how to do that? I searched forum but can't find solution. Please be patinent for newbie. Thank you!

**EDIT 1**

My Findbitmap look like :

```
private bool FindBitmap(Bitmap bmpNeedle, Bitmap bmpHaystack, out Point location)
```

Comment: `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(wpt1)` should solve your issue. If it has to return string only then `Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(wpt1)` should help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources)

Comment: Chetan Ranparyia I can't do that like you said because its a bitmap. Look my edited post.

Comment: @Ash in your example is Image i have Bitmap here try do it like in example  , but i can't do that.

Comment: @Michael, `Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(wpt1);` That is basically what `Resources` class does (`Resources.Designer.cs` file in project folder)