# CS-Script for notepad++ prepare exe for distribution with icon

Tags: c#, notepad++, exe, cs-script

I'm a complete newbie at C#
I'm using Notepad++ for coding with CS-Script plugin for notepad++.
I've developed a little script in it.

In such script I use a traybar icon that I made myself and I included a reference to it in the script with the following row of code

```
trayIcon.Icon = new Icon("icon.ico");
```

That works almost as I need... but look at the following image for clarification:

[image: Binary with the embedded Icon file]

Than I prepare the exe for distribution with the CS-Script command and it works beautifully. The problem is that the compiling procedure doesn't include the icon into the binary file so I must include by hands the icon file it self into the same directory of the binary file: in fact the exe file generated hangs with an error if icon file isn't included.

### Question:

Is there a way to solve the problem and make the "binary package" all in one file with both the executable part and the ico resource file altogether?

### Constraints:

I know I can create a rar, zip, or compressed exe (self-extracting file) but I don't mean that: I want 1 exe file with the icon in it that can be executed and moved stand alone.
In other word the icon has to be embedded into the stand alone exe because it is the exe file icon itself and the icon for the windows traybar.

[image: Screenshot of CS-Script in Notepad++]

Comment: Please try to use ```css_resource``` directive to include your icon to the binary. http://www.csscript.net/help/Using_Resources.html

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh Tnx for response: I've inserted the following code **//css_resource icon.ico;** and the file now is included, (the exe is bigger than before) but still it is not used as exe icon and the exe still hangs if the icon isn't into the directory.

Comment: Link in my previous comment contains usage sample (last snippet with ```ResourceManager```). Also you can check this question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh I had a look on the links you posted and I made some modifications to my code but still not working: I'm getting errors: error CS0103: The name 'Resources' doesn't exist in the current context.
e:\C# Scripts\ScreenShots.cs(77,20): error CS0029: Impossible to convert implicit the type System.Drawing.Bitmap' in 'System.Drawing.Icon' error CS0103: The name 'Assembly' non esiste nel contesto corrente.
e:\C# Scripts\ScreenShots.cs(71,19): error CS1061:

Comment: 'System.Resources.ResourceManager' doesn't contain a definition of 'ResourceManager' and it was not found any method of extension  'ResourceManager'. **I've translated the errors texts from my language that is not English** I hope this helps Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this way to get `Icon` from the embedded resources in the CS-Script compiled binary. Icon file name is `alpha.ico`.

Please pay attention to the `using` section.

```
//css_resource alpha.ico

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

class Script
{
    [STAThread]
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("alpha.ico"))
        {
            var icon = new Icon(stream);
        }
    }
}
```