# Load image to image box using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to load an image to picture box the below way worked with me.

```
image1.Image = Properties.Resources._0;
```

what it i want make the code reading from resources as variable name like the way below.

```
var imagename = _0;

image1.Image = Properties.Resources.imagename;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592150/load-image-from-resources)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ResourceManager` and pass it a `string`:

```
var imageName = "_0";
image1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(imageName);
```