# Convert resource to byte[]

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having trouble converting an image resource into byte[].

For example, I have the following resource:

```
pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Assets/Images/sampleimage.jpg
```

in my program. How do I convert this into a byte[].

I've tried using a BitMapImage, but it's ImageSource ends up being null after initialised.

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-in-c-sharp) about image resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
info.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
return memoryStream.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

A general solution to convert a `BitmapSource` into a `byte[]` would look like this:

```
public byte[] GetImageBuffer(BitmapSource bitmap, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You would use it like shown below, with any of the [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619208.aspx)s that are available in WPF.

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Assets/Images/sampleimage.jpg");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
var buffer = GetImageBuffer(bitmap, new JpegBitmapEncoder());
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of using a specific encoder vs just turning the image straight to a byte[]?

Comment: You can't "just turn the image straight to a byte[]" when you only have a BitmapSource. That happens to work only when you already have the buffer, for example as a resource or as an image file. As you have that, there is no benefit in your case.

Comment: The only thing here is that you need to provide which type of encoder to use depending on the image format you are working with (png, jpeg, tiff, bmp, gif or wmp). It would be good if in that conversion function "GetImageBuffer" no dependency would be made with the image format you are currently working on. Anyway I faced a similar scenario as GoalMaker and I applied your solution and it works. My scenario is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54679146/wpf-read-all-bytes-from-an-image-located-in-another-project

Comment: The advantage of this solution as opposed to others is that it works for Uris created from a file path like "C:\temp", network places like "\\myServer\path" or packed resources like "pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Path/to/Image.png".  And you always can specify if paths are absolute or relative by indicating it as a parameter to the URI using UriKind.Relative, UriKind.Absolute or even UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute to detect it automatically if you need to.