# C#- Resource cannot be found for BITmap

Tags: winforms

I am getting issue in below line :

```
 taskbarNotifier2.SetBackgroundBitmap(new Bitmap(GetType(),"skin2.bmp"), Color.FromArgb(247, 247, 247));
```

Resource **'skin2.bmp'** cannot be found in class **'WindowsFormsApplication2.Form1'**.

Comment: And have you added it as a resource?

Comment: I m nt getting you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/132125/resource-file-error.aspx

Comment: @user1555245 Please try to explain your problem briefly,it actually doesn't tell what you are facing,nor did you have replied to any comments that asked you for the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To use a `Bitmap(Image) Resource` from the project resources,follow these steps;

- Open `Project Properties` in Visual Studio (press Alt+F7).
- Open the `Resources Tab` in Project Properties page.
- In the `Resources Tab` select `Images` in the first drop down list.
- Then select `Add Existing Item` from the second drop down list.
- This opens a `Openfiledialog` asking you to select an image file,go on and select an image    file from any of your folders.
- As you select an image and click on **Open** Button,the selected image gets added to the large blank area in the `Resources Tab`,with a thumbnail image.
- Save the project.

The above steps add an image resource to your project.

Now to access the image resource in your project,use **Properties.Resources.(ResourceName)**,where ResourceName is the name of image (say) that you've added just now.
Please note an image resource returns an `Image` object which you can use anywhere where an `Image` is required.

To explain the last step(assume you have a **PictureBox**,and you want to display the image resource in the **PictureBox**), set the image property of **PictureBox** to this image resource like this;

```
pictureBox1.Image=Properties.Resources.(ResourceName);
```

Make sure to replace **(ResourceName)** with the name of image you've added just now.

Hope it helps you.