# Image resources in object array

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a simple game. I want to use object array to store id of object and an image from resources. How do I do that?

I tried to use `_Properties.Resources_` in array, but it does not work. Is there any way to do this?

This is my array:

```
public object[,] CharacterImages =
    {
        //{id, resource_name}
        {0, 0},
        {1, "flower.bmp"}
    };
```

Comment: See [Load image from resources area of project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Public object[,] CharacterImages =
{       
    {0, global::ProjectName.Properties.Resources.flower.bmp;}
};
```