# Load image from folder in solution - cannot find my picture although its exist in the solution

Tags: c#

I try to load my `Gif` file into my `PitureBox`, after add my picture into my solution so i try:

```
<projectName>.Properties.Resources.<ImageName>;
```

And my `Gif file` not exist after `Resources. options`, other pictures i can see in this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load image from resources area of project in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Again, MyProject.Properties.Resources. cannot find my picture, this is the only picture that i cannot find in my solution

Comment: And, have you set the image's `Build Action` property to `Embedded Resource` in the solution?

Comment: Yes, although other pictures is with default value without Embedded Resource and still exist

Comment: A SSCCE is probably needed here (http://www.sscce.org/)