# How to retrieve a JPG image using GetManifestResourceStream() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following situation:

I have a **Solution** that is named **MySolution**, inside this solution there is some projects including a project named **PdfReport**. Inside this project there is a **folder** named **Shared** and inside this folder there is an **header.jpg** image.

Now I am trying to retrieve this file and I have found this code on the official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287676%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg");
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

On the documentation say that:

> Replace "AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg" with the name of the resource, as
>   it is known in the assembly.

I am finding some difficulties to understand what I have to insert in my specific case as input paramether for the GetManifestResourceStream() method.

Can you help me to retrive my file?

Tnx

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

//first steps
1. you addeed an imager to the project.
2. Right click on the image and change Build Action to Embedded Resource.
[Right click on the image and change Build Action to Embedded Resource.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CrFz.png)

In your code:
uncomment the line below and add a breakpoint. It will return an array with all the resources listed. Simply find your resource, and replace the "assembly.draft.png" with your resource.

```
//  var d = thisExe.GetManifestResourceNames();
System.IO.Stream file =
 thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream(@"assembly.draft.png");
while ((read = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: you need to show what "ms" instantiated class. you need to define buffer.  I assume buffer is byte[]

Answer (score 0):

`GetManifestResourceStream` takes the name that the resource is stored under in the assembly. The compiler picks that name. As far as I remember the name is pieced together from the assembly name, a namespace name and the file name.

Honestly, what I always do to find the name is to open the compiled assembly in Reflector or any other .NET disassembler and just copy the resource name from there. I admit that this is a primitive technique not based on understanding of the technology but it might serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an embedded resource, you can get it using the name `MySolution.Properties.Resources.ImageFile.jpg`, otherwise use a statement like below

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\shared\ImageFile.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method  String[] fileNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
It will return all files including the namespaces, just take the one that ends with your name:

```
    public static Stream ExtractResourceFile(Assembly assembly, String fileName )
    {
        // get all embedded resource file names including namespace
        String[] fileNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        String resourceName = null;
        String temp = "." + fileName.ToUpper();
        foreach (var item in fileNames)
            if (item.ToUpper().EndsWith(temp))
                resourceName = item;
        if (resourceName == null)
            throw new Exception("Embedded resource [" + fileName + "] not found");
        Tracer.Debug("Resource file name [{0}] found as [{1}]", fileName, resourceName);

        // get stream
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
            if (stream == null)
                throw new Exception("Embedded resource [" + resourceName + "] could not be opened.");
        return stream;
    }
```