# Relative path to image file in console application

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application which references a dll DomainLayer.
In DomainLayer, one of the classes uses a image in DomainLayer to display.

Currently I am using the exact path to that image.

How can I use a relative path to this image so that it gets picked up by both tests and Console Application

This is how the hierarchy looks:

-DomainLayer
--Resources
---Images
-----Logo.png

-ConsoleApplication

-UnitTests

Here's the code:

```
  workSheetIntroduction.Pictures.Add(5,1, @"C:\Users\Charu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AsmEpmReports\EmpReports.DomainLayer\Resources\Images\EpmLogo.png");
```

Comment: Could you give a code sample of what you are currently doing?

Comment: You should use the image as a resource, not load it from disk. Set your image file's property to `Embedded Resource` and see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp) post on how to load it.

Comment: @nvoigt I can't do that. The client has asked to use a relative path to an Image

Comment: @friedkiwi added code sample

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `"EmpReports.DomainLayer\Resources\Images\EpmLogo.png"` if the application is being run from `"C:\Users\Charu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AsmEpmReports\"`?

Also, make sure the resources are being copied to the output directory and that you reference the DLLs properly from within the solution.