# Program Dosnt let to print a rectangle - c#

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have A program where i want to print an image to the form( in this case a coin)
But The Program wont let me do that.
it stops at the last line the crash is ArgumentException

heres The Code:

```
Random _Random = new Random();
            Image _CoinImage;
            int height;
            int width;
            Graphics g;
            public Coin(int Height,int Width,Graphics gr)
            {
                _CoinImage = Properties.Resources.Coin;
                height = Height;
                width = Width;
                g = gr;//gr = the form paint
                CoinRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, Height);
                g.DrawImage(_CoinImage, CoinRec); //Crashes Here
            }
```

Comment: What's the exact nature of the "crash"? Is an exception raised? If so which one?

Comment: Why CoinRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, Height); is like this?  width with lower case and Height uppercase?

Comment: @klaymen I suspect that's a typo. The code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Thats a typo  @klaymen

Answer (score 2):

The only overload of [`DrawImage` that takes an `Image` and a `Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40(v=vs.110).aspx) raises `ArgumentNullException` if the image is null:

> [ArgumentNullException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)  image is **null**.

Either check that the image has been loaded correctly and don't call `DrawImage` or trap the exception. Which you do depends on how likely it is that the image is null.

As Marcelo points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467257/program-dosnt-let-to-print-a-rectangle-c-sharp/38467434#comment64338940_38467434) you aren't loading the image correctly which is why it's null.

As the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192071/59303) to that question shows you need to load it like this:

> var bmp = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myimage);

Comment: Complementing @ChrisF's suggestion, to properly load an image from a project's Properties, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Its definitely not Null