# set default image path

Tags: c#, image, winforms

how do i set a default image when the image file was not found or not exist ?
the error i got was

[image]

because file with name `8813.jgp` was not exist. and i want to set it default as `1.jpg`. how do i check if its exist or not.

iam using this code

```
 public void profilepicture()
    {
    DataTable dtprofile = new DataTable();
    DataSet dsprofile = new DataSet();
    string path;
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            dsprofile.Clear();
            dtprofile.Clear();
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "//some query//'";

            myConnection.Open();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dtprofile);
            adapter.Fill(dsprofile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        path = dsprofile.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "\\" + number + ".jpg";
        pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile(path);

        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if the file exists using `File.Exists()` in the `System.IO` namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if(File.Exists("filePath"))
{
    // Load file.
}
else
{
    // Load default file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite trivial actually!

```
path = dsprofile.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + "\\" + number + ".jpg";
if(File.Exists(path)){
    pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
}
else
{
    pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile("NotFound.jpg");
}
```

Comment: well, i dont know, a system.io of `file.exists`. chill ~

Comment: Include the namespace for System.IO

    using System.IO;

it exists in the Assembly mscorlib.dll which i am sure you would have already!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a separate method to get the SQL Table, so you can use it in every method you need and then you create a different method for the profile picture using the code as below:

```
public DataTable GetSqlTable(string query)
{
    using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source={ServerName};Initial Catalog={DB_Name};UID={UserID}; Password={PWD}"))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, dbConnection);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 600000; //optional
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Update(dt);
            dbConnection.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            dbConnection.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public void profilepicture()
{
    DataTable dt = GetSqlTable("/* some query */");
    string number = "some value";
    string defaultImg = "defaultImgPath";
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string path = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + "\\" + number + ".jpg";
        pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile(File.Exists(path) ? path : defaultImg);
    }
    else
    {
        pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile(defaultImg);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

**Standalone applications**

If your application is a standalone application (requires only exe and no other files in hard disk), you can add the default image in a resource file and use it as required. Following stack overflow link explains how to access images added into a resource file [Load image from resources area of project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

```
pictureEdit2.Image = File.Exists(path) ? Image.FromFile(path) : Resources.myImage;
```

**Installed applications**

If your application is not a standalone application, you can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx) method or [`Application.StartupPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the default image.

To avoid file not found exception, you may need to use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code something like below

```
string defaultImagePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\1.jpg";
pictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromFile( File.Exists(path) ? path : defaultImagePath) ;
```