# How to figure out what to cast a resource to after loading it from an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to access the resources in an assembly I didn't write; here's what it looks like in DnSpy:

[image: DnSpy tree]

If I call GetManifestResourceNames on the assembly it only returns '0a58be7b.Resources.resources".
I want to access the images inside it but I have no idea what to cast it to so I can.

what do I do?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192076/6443307
Although, I suppose in your case you can't use `GetEntryAssembly`; you'll have to specify the target assembly another way.  But the point about using `GetManifestResourceStream` and creating a new `Bitmap` is the important part.

Comment: like I said in post, I can't use GetManifestResourceNames because it only returns the parent name, and I have no idea what that is or how to access it's children.
I know how to load bitmaps from a stream, I just have no idea how to access them