# Displaying an image that is stored in the solution c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to display an image in a picture box which I have saved in my solution folder.

[image]

Is there an easy way for this to be done? I have seen examples of loading from resources using streams etc. But that seems far too much code for what I'm trying to do.

```
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GDPRState"].ToString() == "1")
    {
         picture_GDPR.Image = Image.FromFile("");
    }
```

Do I want to be using the FromFile function to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from resources area of project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My image isn't save in the resources location though?

Comment: When you try using `FromFile`, does it work?

Comment: No, I get the IO.FileNotFoundException

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't copied your image file to the build directory.

Comment: I hadn't put the image in the correct location, I just copied my image in rather than adding as a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQMDsJgMXhE

The above YouTube video helped explain it to me.

I had just copied my image into the directory and not added it as a resource. When I had added it correctly the following code worked.

```
picture_GDPR.Image = Properties.Resources.gdpr_test;
```