# How do use the image I added to the Resources? C#

Tags: c#, image, resources

I have a button, and I want to change the image of it everytime it is clicked. The images are at the Resources. How do I call them?

btnIden.Image = //HERE ;

Comment: Winforms, WPf, web ?

Comment: It is winforms...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from resources area of project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
btnIden.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources.image
```

where

> image

is a name of the file you uploaded without an extension. Or how do you call it in a project properties.

Answer (score 0):

You just call the image in the resource by name

```
btnIden.Image = MyProject.Properties.Resources.img_name_in_resource
```

Comment: Error 1 'Theseseses.Properties.Resources' does not contain a definition for 'select' C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Theseseses\Theseseses\Form3.cs 30 65 Theseseses

Comment: select is my file name. select.png to be exact