# Load Picture In Picture Box Based on Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

So I have my resource folder full of pictures, and I know to load one into a picturebox, its

```
picPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.Imagename
```

But I created a method that will return me the name of one of my pictures. I've tried doing

```
picPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.GetImage()
```

but that doesn't work. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What does your method return? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: This: `(Image)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("nameofimage");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JonasH my method returns a string, containing the name of the image.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks homie, your solution worked.