# Using a PictureBox to get a randomized picture

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I have imported 5 images into the resources folder on my project. The image names are Blackcar, Redcar, Bluecar, Yellowcar, Greencar. When I run this program I want the PictureBox to randomly display one of these images so it is different every time I run this program.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String[] imgs = { "Blackcar", "Bluecar", "Greencar", "Yellowcar," "Redcar" };
  int randomIndex;
  Random r = new Random();

  randomIndex = r.Next(imgs.Length);
  pictureBox1.Image = imgs[randomIndex];
}
```

I know I cannot convert the string array to the PictureBox, but I'm not sure how to make this work. I am getting the error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type string to 'System.Drawing.Image'

Comment: Putting aside the fact that `Random` is not static, where should the image data be loaded from? If you choose "Blackcar", where's the image? A file?

Comment: @gunr2171 I have saved these images under downloads on my computer, but I imported them into the 'Resources' file in my project.

Comment: Use an image list

Comment: Are the images set as EMBEDDED RESOURCES?

Comment: Use something like: `pictureBox.Image = Bitmap.FromResource(......);`, see: [Load image from resources area of project in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Set your images as EMBEDDED RESOURCES, then use code like this:

```
private Random R = new Random();

private Image[] imgs = {
    Properties.Resources.Blackcar,
    Properties.Resources.Bluecar,
    Properties.Resources.Greencar,
    Properties.Resources.Yellowcar,
    Properties.Resources.Redcar
};

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = imgs[R.Next(imgs.Length)];
}
```