How do I add a resource as a bitmap to my C# project in Visual Studio 2022?
I know this is probably a dumb question but I've been literally trying to achieve this for like 4 hours. I looked up and down everywhere, asked ChatGPT but I was not able to find a solution.
My project is a Windows Forms project.
I can only add the resource as either an Icon or Byte[]:

The icon apparently has to be square, which I don't want and attempting to convert the Byte[] to Image via:
private static Image ImageFromByte(byte[] b)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
    return Image.FromStream(ms);
}

This however throws an "out of memory" error.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

@wohlstad It's winforms. Sorry, forgot to mention it. I updated the question as well.

Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192054/load-image-from-resources-area-of-project-in-c-sharp.

@wohlstad that answers how to access the image once it is added. My problem is that I can't even add it. I can only add it as an Icon or a Byte[] but not as a Bitmap.

Apart from what wohlstad said, try this maybe! https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576471/18893220

@andrewb I used the method from the accepted answer here and managed to load an image stored as byte[] from resource and set it as the Image of a PictureBox on my form.

@wohlstad thank you but that method was throwing out of memory error for me when I attempted to set the image as a backgroundImage of a button. You can look at shingo's answer below to see what I needed.

Update
The latest Visual Studio can choose Bitmap as the image type now:


I think this is a problem with the new resource editor, you can use the legacy editor to add images as Bitmap objects.

Right click on the .resx file and click "Open With..."


Choose "Managed Resources Editor (Legacy)", you can also click "Set as Default" to make it the default editor.




Another approach is to click F7 on the .resx file to edit the XML content and manually change the image type you inserted to System.Drawing.Bitmap
<data name="MyImage" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <!--value>Resources\MyImage.jpg;System.Byte[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value-->
    <value>Resources\MyImage.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>


YES. MY SAVIOR!!!! I am actually crying happy tears right now. Oh god why did they remove this feature???

@andrewb I wonder that about a lot of stuff in modern VS, to the point I tend to just copy old 2012 projects and solutions and replace the GUIDs in them instead of using the new types...
