# Retrieve images name from the resources - c#

Tags: c#

I'd like to get the name of all the images from resources and store them in a ListBox. Should i loop through and declare it as array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598484/how-to-retrieve-image-from-resources-folder-of-the-project-in-c-sharp

Comment: Are you using winforms, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: i don't know WPF or Silverlight just plain visual c# 2008

Comment: i really don't have a code yet. but i think the logic was like this
>int x = 0;  
>pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(x);

Answer (score 0):

Use [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames.aspx)

Comment: is it possible to call its index number(if it has one)?
(i don't know how to call it since i am new to this stuff)

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? It returns an array, so yes, you can use indexers. But, from what you post, I think this is way over your knowledge at this point (no pun intended). Try to learn first the technology, the language, etc...